# How to Add\retrieve ParseObject in a ParseArray ?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a class named User which contains a array named PNRS .
Now i want PNRS to be a array of ParseObject of class named PnrFetch .

So here is what i did

```
ParseObject inputPnrobject= new ParseObject("PnrFetch");

inputPnrobject.put("PnrID", userpnr);

try
{
inputPnrobject.save();
}

currentUser.addUnique("Pnrs",inputPnrobject);

currentUser.saveInBackground();
```

But when i retrieve this array

```
JSONArray  myjson=currentUser.getJSONArray("Pnrs");
```

myjson has null values in it.things were working fine in older dashboard. I don't know what changed now.

Comment: If you go to the parse web interface, can you see the object added to the current user?

Comment: If i work on old dashboard yes it is working fine . But when i switch to new dashboard it adds null .
it shows nothing on dashboard but when i retrieve in myjson shows null added .it is rare case  but  my app is breaking because of that